# is there any word to describe a person (or a phenomenon) that can accomplish contradictory things?

Tags: single-word-requests, oxymoron, contradiction

For example, if someone is given to finish two contradictory things (or we can say task) and he/she would accomplish all at the same time. 
It's like oxymoron, but somebody can handle those kind of situation.
Is there any word for that?

Comment: reading the question, paradox comes to my mind first

Comment: If the two tasks are truly contradictory, I would call them a miracle worker. If they only appear contradictory, then I would just call them a person :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could say the completion of both those things (or tasks) as a whole is **dichotomous**. [According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dichotomous), dichotomous means:

> "involving two completely opposing ideas or things"[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dichotomous)

Some examples [from ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomous):

> "‘Crewdson's work is replete with dichotomous tensions.’" [2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomous)
>
> "‘This view emphasizes the dichotomous thinking and behavior often displayed by alcoholics.’" [2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomous)
>
> "‘The forced-choice format is used with each item presented separately and each pole representing a dichotomous extreme for one attitude or function.’" [2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomous)

According to ODO, a **dichotomist** is:

> "A person who dichotomizes or classifies by dichotomy."

So in your case you could the person (or phenomenon) you described a dichotomist. I should add that the word isn't commonly used (only 18,000 hits on Google). It is, however, a proper word and has been used since the 1860s ([according to this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dichotomist&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdichotomist%3B%2Cc0)).

#### Attribution

[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dichotomous) Dichotomous Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary. (n.d.). Retrieved March 23, 2018, from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dichotomous

[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomous) Dichotomous | Definition of dichotomous in English by Oxford Dictionaries. (n.d.). Retrieved March 23, 2018, from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomous

[3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomist) Dichotomist | Definition of dichotomist in English by Oxford Dictionaries. (n.d.). Retrieved March 23, 2018, from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dichotomist